# Mysql not matching strings in two different fields

Tags: php, mysql, matching

I have two different tables in mysql that have fields named 'topic', both which contain the same data.  Both are text type fields.  The records in these fields consist of one to three capitalized words, such as "AGRICULTURE" and "RAINFALL AMOUNTS".

I am finding it impossible, however, to construct a mysql query that will find matches between these two tables.

The following mysql statements yield no results, even though tables A and B contain the same data in the 'topic' field:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE topic = '$TableBTopic'
SELECT * FROM TableA MATCH(topic) AGAINST ('$TableBTopic' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE topic LIKE '%$TableBTopic%'
```

I think I finally got something to work, but it only returned half the actual matches.

I've been using PHP for over a decade and have never run into this problem.  It could be that I have never attempted to compare record data between two tables like this.

I tried creating an Index on the topic field, but that did not help either, though perhaps I did that incorrectly.  I thought, however, that indexes were for large data sets and these two fields contain only about 100 records each.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: if you done thus 10 years then you must an expert, but here you need to provide the create tabel of both tables with data and wanted result see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is there a reason why you've got two identical tables in the database? Anyway yes, as above you really need to provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant sample data and expected result. We cannot guess what's in your table or might be causing any issue. See also [ask] and the [tour] for more guidance. You can [edit] your post when you're ready. Then it should be easier to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I'll work on providing more details.  I do not have two identical tables.  I have two different tables. But each of the different tables has a field called "topic", as well as other fields that are unique to that particular table.

Comment: My bad, I misread it. But anyway yes we will need some more info realistically before we can help

Comment: Thanks. I've solved it.  When you brought up the subject of how I created the tables, it got me thinking.  I went back and re-created the table and tried everything step by step, and this time it worked!